# How do I use elsif and ranges?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
var_comparison = 5
print "Please enter a number: "
my_num = Integer(gets.chomp)
if my_num > var_comparison
    print "You picked a number greater than 5!"
elsif my_num < var_comparison
    print "You picked a number less than 5!"
elsif my_num > 99
    print "Your number is too large, man."
else
    print "You picked the number 5!"
end
```

The interpreter has no way of distinguishing between accepting the rule `>5` or `>99`. How do I make it so that any number between 6-99 returns "You picked a number greater than 5!", but a number 100 or greater returns "Your number is too large, man!"?

Do I need to specifically state a range somehow? How would I best do that? Would it by the normal range methods e.g.

```
if my_num 6..99
```

or

```
if my_num.between(6..99)
```

?

Comment: Since this is your first programming language: I'd suggest something more meaningful than `var_comparison` for a variable name. Maybe `threshold` or similar. Generally you want the code to read as easily as possible, and I would say `if my_num > threshold` is more readable than `if my_num > var_comparison`.

Comment: Hi Cereal. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll certainly try and do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express it as a range, but it would be much simpler to rearrange the order of your conditions to achieve what you want. The interpreter runs through conditional if/else statements in the order they are written, stopping when a condition is true or when `else` is reached. This makes the order important. We can know that if I get to an `elsif`, all the preceding conditions must have been false. So in your code:

```
var_comparison = 5
print "Please enter a number: "
my_num = Integer(gets.chomp)
if my_num > 99
    # my_num is > 99
    print "Your number is too large, man."
elsif my_num > var_comparison # to get here, my_num must be <= 99
    print "You picked a number greater than 5!"
elsif my_num < var_comparison
    print "You picked a number less than 5!"
else
    print "You picked the number 5!"
end
```

If you needed to express a number as a range (if your conditional logic becomes more complex), you could do the following:

```
if (6..99).cover?(my_num)
```

Comment: Ah ha. This makes sense. Thank you! How would you choose between .covers, .between etc?

Comment: After reading the docs (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F), I don't see much difference between `.cover?` (not `.covers?`, fixed typo above sorry) and `.between?` except who is the asker and the askee. `.cover?` has potential performance benefits over `.include?` (and `.between?` seems to have similar benefits), which is why I would generally recommend it. I don't to a _whole_ lot of Ruby, so I can't say which you'd more commonly see, so hopefully someone else can give a better distinction.

Answer (score 2):

> Clearly the interpreter has no way of distinguishing between accepting the rule >5 or >99.

Yes it does: it tests the conditions in textual order! Since 100 is both greater than 5 and greater than 99, both conditions match, but in an if/elseif chain only one condition is ever evaluated. You should move the clauses around to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'm struggling to grasp quite what you mean. Do you mean that if I enter 100 then because it is >5, it will not evaluate subsequent rules? It merely returns true?

So, I need to establish a chain that, in the case of gets.chomp = 100, then each will be 'false' until the final else command?

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the meaning of `else` is "only if there wasn't already a `true` encountered".

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `elseif`, use `case`/`when`:

```
def test_range(foo)
  case foo
  when 5 .. 99
    puts "#{ foo } is in range"
  else
    puts "#{ foo } is out of range"
  end
end

test_range(4)
test_range(5)
test_range(99)
test_range(100)
# >> 4 is out of range
# >> 5 is in range
# >> 99 is in range
# >> 100 is out of range
```

In your code's case, it needs to be a bit different, because testing for less-than and greater-than doesn't lend itself to the normal range tests, because they expect discrete minimum and maximum values. So, instead, this is what I'd do:

```
my_num = 5
case 
when my_num > 99
  puts "Your number is too large, man."
when my_num > 5
  puts "You picked a number greater than 5!"
when my_num < 5
  puts "You picked a number less than 5!"
else
  puts "You picked the number 5!"
end
```

I find that long chains of `if`/`elseif`/`else` become harder to read, so I prefer `case` statements.

Answer (score 0):

As Kilian said, if clauses are evaluated in order, so the first to match is considered the chosen one.

You can even use `case; when` to achieve this:

```
Infinity = 1.0/0

var_comparison = 5
print "Please enter a number: "
my_num = Integer(gets.chomp)
case my_num
  when -Infinity...var_comparison
    puts "You picked a number less than #{var_comparison}!"
  when var_comparison
    puts "You picked the number #{var_comparison}!"
  when var_comparison..99
    puts "You picked a number greater than #{var_comparison}!"
  else
    puts "Your number is too large, man."
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Why would you need the infinity variable in addition to define the range? the Tin Man above stuck to < 5. Does it convey any advantage to using if (6..99).cover?(my_num)?

Sorry if these questions sound dumb. Just trying to get my head around all angles as, for even a simple question, there are many different solutions.

Comment: @MattKneale - not at all. The Tin Man's solution is different than mine, since mine declares against what to check (so I don't have to repeat `my_num` at every `when`). This syntax is equivalent to have `when my_num === ...` at each when. `(6..99).cover?(my_num)` is _exactly_ the same as `(6..99) === my_num`.